# Netty WriteAndFlush getting stuck intermittently

Tags: netty

**Netty Server Bootstrap:**

```
EventLoopGroup bg = new NioEventLoopGroup(1, new CamelThreadFactory("Thread#", "NettyServerTCPBoss", false));
EventLoopGroup wg = new NioEventLoopGroup(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2, new CamelThreadFactory("Thread#", "NettyServerTCPWorker", false));
ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
serverBootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE,true);
serverBootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
```

**Netty Pipeline Config:**

```
    ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
    ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new RequestPayloadDecoder())); //This extends ByteToMessageDecoder
    ch.pipeline().addLast("idlehandler", new IdleStateHandler(..));
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(100),"handler", new 
org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler());
```

**Setting AutoRead to false**

```
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
InetSocketAddress clientAddress = ((InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress());
ctx.channel().config().setAutoRead(false);
ctx.channel().read();
}
```

**Handler Logic on channelRead0()**

```
 public void process(ChannelHandlerContext nettyChannelContext) throws Exception {
    if(validate() && channel.isWritable()){
    outboundMessages = //get from database
    for(List<Outbound> outbound : outboundMessages){
    if(channel().isWritable()){
    ChannelFuture writeFuture = nettyChannelContext.channel().writeAndFlush(outbound.getString()); //Send the message
    writeFuture.sync(); // wait for the IO to complete
    logger.info("Updating message status for event row id {}",outbound.getRowId);
    updateMessageStatusInDb(outbound);
    } } }
    ctx.channel.read();//Call read() after writes are done to process next inbound message 
    }
```

**Question**
Everything seem to work fine but intermittently it is getting stuck at writeFuture.sync() for more than 10 minutes. I have tried using a listener instead of sync(). But it takes a similar time to receive the operationComplete() callback. 
**Sample Logs:**
2019-06-18 14:16:39.263 [Camel Thread #20 - NettyEventExecutorGroup] INFO Updating message status for event row id::: 40257
2019-06-18 14:16:39.265 [Camel Thread #20 - NettyEventExecutorGroup] INFO Updating message status for event row id::: 40263
**2019-06-18 14:16:39.266** [Camel Thread #20 - NettyEventExecutorGroup] INFO Updating message status for event row id::: 40269
**2019-06-18 14:30:09.982** [Camel Thread #20 - NettyEventExecutorGroup] INFO Updating message status for event row id::: 40275
2019-06-18 14:30:09.987 [Camel Thread #20 - NettyEventExecutorGroup] INFO Updating message status for event row id::: 42691
Why is the IO taking so long to complete, for every 30k messages that were sent, this happens to 40-50 messages. Can you please provide some pointers?

Comment: Why do you need to wait for the writeFuture to complete?

Comment: I want to update the status of that record in the db only after the write is successful. I have tried moving this logic to a Future listener as well but it still takes a long time to get the callback on future complete.